# Visual Studio C/C++ : Access to call stack from the code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, callstack

Is there a way to access to call stack content from the code ?
There are many introspection functions in `<crtdbg.h>` but none about call stack.
(at least, I didn't find any)
I need some (MSVC-non-standard) function that returns an array of structs, where each one would tell a function call with its name,file,line...

Comment: There's [`stacktrace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace) in C++23

Comment: Thx @ChrisMM, but I'm stuck with C++11

Comment: You can use `StackWalk64` and some other functionality from DbgHelp.dll. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/dbghelp-functions This would probably help get you started. https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker

Comment: What platform?  I believe the best route is to write an assembly language function that uses the stack pointer (register) to print out the stack values.

Comment: Boost Stacktrace?